# Multithreading in Ubuntu 11.10 Vmware

Tags: pthreads

I'm writing a multithread program in C++ using "pthread" libraries, but when I come to execute it on Ubuntu Virtual machine, my threads don't seem to run in parallel although I have a multicore processor (i7-2630QM)... the code is too long so I'm going to explain my problem with this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

void* myfunction(void* arg); //function that the thread will execute

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myfunction, NULL); //thread created
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) //show "1" 10 times
         cout << "1";
    pthread_join(thread, NULL); //wait for the thread to finish executing
    return 0;
}

void* myfunction(void* arg)
{
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) //show "2" 10 times
         cout << "2";
    return NULL;
}
```

When I run this code on my host OS (Windows 7 with VC++2010) I get a result like `12212121211121212...`, which is what a multithread app supposed to do, but when I run the same code on the guest OS (Ubuntu on Vmware with Code::Blocks) I always get `11111111112222222222` !!!
AFAIK the thread should run in parallel with the main() function, not sequentially. My VM's core number is set to 4, but it seems that the program use only one core, I don't know what is wrong? is it the code or ...? am I missing something here?
I appreciate any help, thanks in advance and please forgive my english :/

Answer (score 0):

Use a semaphore (global or passed as a parameter to my function) to synchronise the threads properly. You're probably running into timing issues due to the different scheduling characteristics between the OSes (it's not really an issue per se). Have the first thread wait on the semaphore after the call to pthread_create, and have the new thread signal it as soon as myfunction is entered.

Also, your loops are quite short, make them take longer.

[example here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~travitch/pthreads_primer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Linux CRT/STDC++ libs have different synchronization behaviors. You can't learn much of anything about parallel execution with calls to `cout`. Write some actual parallel computation and measure elapsed time to tell what's going on.